# Python List Manipulation with Incremental Additions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a python (version3.6 within AWS Glue running PySpark) list:

```
['id', 'account_id', 'lab_order_id', 'match_status', 'report_date', 'message', 'reporting_states', 'state_messages', 'overall_consistency', 'alerts', 'run_datetime_partition', 'run_datetime']
```

I would like to have a resulting string from the list that reads like:

```
$1 "ID", $2 "ACCOUNT_ID", $3 "LAB_ORDER_ID", $4 "MATCH_STATUS", $5 "REPORT_DATE", $6 "MESSAGE", $7 "REPORTING_STATES", $8 "STATE_MESSAGES", $9 "OVERALL_CONSISTENCY", $10 "ALERTS", $11 "RUN_DATETIME"
```

So far I have gotten the string close, without the incrementing $num before each quoted name.  I need the incrementing to be dynamic as not each table will have the same number of columns.

```
# Variable List
column_names = final_table_data_frame.schema.names
column_strings = ('","').join(column_names).upper().replace(',"RUN_DATETIME_PARTITION"','')
var_list = '"' + column_strings + '"'
```

Where the column_names item is sourced from the schema of a previous data frame.  I have tried using a lambda but am running issues with concatenating the results with a string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) + [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and then [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
lst = ['id', 'account_id', 'lab_order_id', 'match_status', 'report_date', 'message', 'reporting_states', 
       'state_messages', 'overall_consistency', 'alerts', 'run_datetime_partition', 'run_datetime']
result = ', '.join([f'${i} "{e.upper()}"' for i, e in enumerate(lst, 1)])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
$1 "ID", $2 "ACCOUNT_ID", $3 "LAB_ORDER_ID", $4 "MATCH_STATUS", $5 "REPORT_DATE", $6 "MESSAGE", $7 "REPORTING_STATES", $8 "STATE_MESSAGES", $9 "OVERALL_CONSISTENCY", $10 "ALERTS", $11 "RUN_DATETIME_PARTITION", $12 "RUN_DATETIME"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come to a solution using a dictionary and some further parsing:

```
column_names = final_table_data_frame.drop("run_datetime_partition").schema.names
dict = dict(enumerate(column_names, start = 1))
column_strings = (',').join(['$%s "%s"' % (key, value) for (key, value) in dict.items()]).upper()
```